# CVE Details API , get vulnerabilities by component

Tags: json, http, parsing, get

I need to get vulnerabilities by component at JSON format, but all I've get by using [CVE Details API](https://www.cvedetails.com) just single vulnerabilities where no components or something, only describe.

Here is an example of link

```
http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=10&vendor_id=0&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opfileinc=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=3&cvssscoremin=0
```

Here is an example of JSON:

```
{
    "cve_id": "CVE-2016-4951",
    "cwe_id": "0",
    "summary": "The tipc_nl_publ_dump function in net/tipc/socket.c in the Linux kernel through 4.6 does not verify socket existence, which allows local users to cause a denial of service (NULL pointer dereference and system crash) or possibly have unspecified other impact via a dumpit operation.",
    "cvss_score": "7.2",
    "exploit_count": "0",
    "publish_date": "2016-05-23",
    "update_date": "2016-05-24",
    "url": "http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2016-4951/"
 }
```

Are there any way to get vulnerabilities by name of component? (new and old)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Red Hat maintains a CVE API that can be searched by component, e.g.:

https://access.redhat.com/labs/securitydataapi/cve.json?package=kernel&after=2017-02-17

Documentation for the API can be found [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_security_data_api/0.1/html-single/red_hat_security_data_api/#cve).

Note that the data is probably limited to components in Red Hat products.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late for a proper reply, but maybe it'll still be useful. A while back I was a bit frustrated with the options available, so I built https://cveapi.com.

You can call GET https://v1.cveapi.com/.json and get the NIST json response for that CVE back.

It doesn't require any auth and is free to use.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to vendor specific CVE API's is [CIRCL's Common Vulnerabilities and Exposure Web Interface and API](https://www.circl.lu/services/cve-search/).

Its web interface can be found at https://cve.circl.lu/ and API documentation here https://cve.circl.lu/api/